# Deploy Window mobile application on Emulator 6.1

Tags: windows-mobile

I want to deploy my windows mobile application on windows Mobile 6 emulator, so that there is no dependency on Visual Studio 2005/2008.

I require this for testing and demo purpose.

Thanks,
Mrinal Jaiswal

Comment: And the question is? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Then download the stand-alone version of [Device Emulator 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=A6F6ADAF-12E3-4B2F-A394-356E2C2FB114&displaylang=en) and the [WinMo emulator images](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1A7A6B52-F89E-4354-84CE-5D19C204498A&displaylang=en) for it.